# Is it possible to disable half of the Stepper

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to disable half of the stepper when the value of the stepper is zero.

I tried the .disabled function on the stepper but it disables the whole stepper and I only want the decrement part of the stepper to be disabled.

```
struct StepperLabelView : View {
    @ObservedObject var social: Social

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Stepper(onIncrement: {
                self.social.quantity += 1
                socialsInCanvas += [Social(companyName: self.social.companyName)]
            }, onDecrement: {
                self.social.quantity -= 1
                socialsInCanvas.removeLast()
            }, label: { Text("") })
                .disabled(social.quantity == 0)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Stepper` can take range to activate each button:

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @State var quantity = 3

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Stepper("Count: \(quantity)", value: $quantity, in: 0...Int.max)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

You can use `onEditingChanged` argument for adding extra work.
Also you can observe on `quantity`:

```
@State var quantity = 3 {
    didSet {
        if oldValue < quantity {
            // Probably + button touched
            return
        }

        if oldValue > quantity {
            // Probably - button touched
            return
        }

        if oldValue == quantity {
            // Unknown
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution but I need to edit the array differently depending if the user pressed the increment or decrement button. Is it possible to know what button is pressed with onEditingChanged?

Comment: You can observer on quantity `didSet` or `willSet`. I updated my answer. hope it helps you more.

Comment: This is a great answer, solved my problem! TIL about oldValue

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your onDecrement code in a conditional or roll your own using two buttons.

```
        HStack {
            Button(
                action: { self.item += "+" },
                label: { Image(systemName: "plus.circle") }
            )
            Text(item)
            Button(
                action: { self.item += "-" },
                label: { Image(systemName: "minus.circle") }
            )
        }
```

Just disable the "-" button when appropriate. The plus.square might be a better symbol, https://sfsymbols.com is a good place to compare them.